# Python 3.9 - Scheduling periodic calls of async function with different parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x, scheduled-tasks, python-asyncio

How to in python 3.9 implement the functionality of calling the async functions with different parameters, by scheduled periods?  The functionality should be working on any OS (Linux, Windows, Mac)

I have a function fetchOHLCV which downloads market data from exchanges. The function has two input parameters - pair, timeframe.
Depending on the pair and timeframe values the function download data from exchanges and stores them in DB.

The goal - call this function with different periods with different parameters.

```
1) fetchOHLCV(pair ='EUR/USD', timeframe="1m") - each minute
2) fetchOHLCV(pair ='EUR/USD', timeframe="1h") - each new hour.
3) fetchOHLCV(pair ='EUR/USD', timeframe="1d") - each new day 
4) fetchOHLCV(pair ='EUR/USD', timeframe="1w") - each new week
```

At this moment I don't have experience working with scheduling in python and I don't know which libraries will optimal for my task and I'm interested in the best practices of implementing similar tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a ready-to-use solution, you could use [`aiocron`](https://github.com/gawel/aiocron) library. If you are not familiar with [cron](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) expression syntax, you can use [this](https://crontab.guru/) online editor to check.

Example (this will work on any OS):

```
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime
import aiocron


async def foo(param):
    print(datetime.now().time(), param)


async def main():
    cron_min = aiocron.crontab('*/1 * * * *', func=foo, args=("At every minute",), start=True)
    cron_hour = aiocron.crontab('0 */1 * * *', func=foo, args=("At minute 0 past every hour.",), start=True)
    cron_day = aiocron.crontab('0 9 */1 * *', func=foo, args=("At 09:00 on every day-of-month",), start=True)
    cron_week = aiocron.crontab('0 9 * * Mon', func=foo, args=("At 09:00 on every Monday",), start=True)

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
15:26:00.003226 At every minute
15:27:00.002642 At every minute
...
```

Comment: The last update of asyncio was two years ago. Is it an alive project? Is it compatible with python 3.9 and the new asyncio lib?

Comment: `asyncio` has not changed significantly in Python 3.9, and this example is fully compatible with it

Answer (score 5):

Here you use [apschedulers](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html)AsyncIOScheduler which works naturally with async functions

```
scheduler = AsyncIOScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(fetchOHLCV, trigger=tr)
scheduler.start()
```

tr is trigger object. You can use either `IntervalTrigger` or a `CronTrigger`to schedule it. Its recommended to do a `shutdown()` on the scheduler object after the end of program

OR alternatively

You can use [run_coroutine_threadsafe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe)to schedule a coroutine to the event loop

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(async_function(), bot.loop)
```

Working example of `asyncio` on `Python3.9`

```
import asyncio

async def periodic():
    while True:
        print('periodic')
        await asyncio.sleep(1) #you can put 900 seconds = 15mins

def stop():
    task.cancel()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.call_later(5, stop) #increase end time as per your requirement
task = loop.create_task(periodic())

try:
    loop.run_until_complete(task)
except asyncio.CancelledError:
    pass
```

[image: implementation]

So as you can see async function was called with the scheduling of `1second` and `stop` function was called at `5th second`. Try implementing this and could possibly solve your problem

Comment: is not clear how to add a job which will call async function every 15 minutes. For example  XX:00:00, XX:15:00, XX:30:00, XX:45:00. Can you share an example? And the library should not use any database for store configuration.

Comment: I have updated my answer with an working example on ```python3.9```. Try implementing this way